# Is there a Dart equivalent to PHP "Hash_init" "Hash_update" "Hash_Final" for Sha256

Tags: php, dart, hash, sha256

The object is to make pass-hash for an AES file.

```
PHP
$aes_key = str_pad($iv, self::KEY_SIZE, hex2bin("00"));
for ($i = 0; $i < self::HASH_ITERATION; $i++) {
    $hash = hash_init("sha256");
    hash_update($hash, $aes_key);
    hash_update($hash, $passphrase);
    $aes_key = hash_final($hash, true);
}
return $aes_key;
```

I don't know if

```
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
```

has an action that matches hash_init, hash_update, hash_final.

Comment: I would suggest using a proven key stretching algo like PBKDF2 rather than trying to roll your own like this.

Comment: Also this usage is equivalent to `hash('sha256', $aes_key . $passphrase, true);` which will likely simplify your search for a Dart equivalent. https://3v4l.org/XZTvR

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into the PBKDF2.